# Angular migration 'path' message

Tags: angular

I am trying to update angular 8 to angular 9 but during migration this error occurred. I don't have any clue what causing this error.

[image: Error message]

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "baseUrl": "",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "paths": {
            "stream": ["../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js"],
            "zlib": ["../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js"],
            "globalize": [ "../node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize" ],
            "globalize/*": [ "../node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/*" ],
            "cldr": [ "../node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr" ],
            "cldr/*": [ "../node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/*" ],
            "jszip": [ "../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js" ],
            /* Custom paths */
            "@ht/core": [ "app/core/index" ],
            "@ht/components/warehouse-tree-view": [ "app/common/warehouses-tree-view/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route-point-tasks-modal": [ "app/modals/route-point-tasks/index" ],
            "@ht/common/track-api-urls": [ "app/api-client/index" ],
            "@ht/common/application-links": [ "app/common/application-links/index" ],
            "@ht/common/daterange-picker": [ "app/common/daterange-picker/index" ],
            "@ht/common/grid-date-filter": [ "app/common/grid-date-filter/index" ],
            "@ht/common/gallery": [ "app/common/gallery/index" ],
            "@ht/common/map": [ "app/common/map/index" ],
            "@ht/service/rodo": [ "app/services/rodo.service" ],
            "@ht/service/auth": [ "app/state/auth/api-service/index" ],
            "@ht/store/ui-state-storage": [ "app/common/ui-state-storage/index" ],
            "@ht/store/geocoding-status": [ "app/common/geocoding-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/rodo-status": [ "app/common/rodo-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/gif-expiration-status": [ "app/common/gif-expiration-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/gif-state": [ "app/common/gif-state/index" ],
            "@ht/store/invoice-kind": [ "app/common/invoice-kind/index" ],
            "@ht/store/invoice-payment-status": [ "app/common/invoice-payment-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/package-type": [ "app/common/package-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/temperature-status": [ "app/common/temperature-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/exceedance-type": [ "app/common/exceedance-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/grid-settings": [ "app/common/grid-settings/index" ],
            "@ht/store/attachment": [ "app/common/attachment/index" ],
            "@ht/store/distribution-center": [ "app/common/distribution-center/index" ],
            "@ht/store/temperature-recorder": [ "app/common/temperature-recorder/index" ],
            "@ht/store/user-warehouse": [ "app/common/user-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-status": [ "app/common/route-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-point-status": [ "app/common/route-point-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/role": [ "app/common/role/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-optimalization": [ "app/common/optimalization/route/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-detail-tooltip": [ "app/common/route-detail-tooltip/index" ],
            "@ht/store/warehouse": [ "app/common/warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/store/cmd-status": [ "app/common/cmd-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/waybill-status": [ "app/common/waybill-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/loading-list-state": [ "app/common/loading-list-state/index" ],
            "@ht/store/currency": [ "app/common/currency/index" ],
            "@ht/store/device-assignment-type": [ "app/common/device-assignment-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/device-ownership-type": [ "app/common/device-ownership-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/device-state": [ "app/common/device-state/index" ],
            "@ht/store/document-kp-status": [ "app/common/document-kp-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/invoice-payment-method": [ "app/common/invoice-payment-method/index" ],
            "@ht/store/transport-company-type": [ "app/common/transport-company-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/invoice-status": [ "app/common/invoice-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/alternative-geocoding-status": [ "app/common/alternative-geocoding-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/seal-condition": [ "app/common/seal-condition/index" ],
            "@ht/store/truck": [ "app/common/truck/index" ],
            "@ht/store/truckType": [ "app/common/truck-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/truckClass": [ "app/common/truck-class/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-type": [ "app/common/route-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/attachment-object-type": [ "app/common/attachment-object-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/contact-type": [ "app/common/contact-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/print-type": [ "app/common/print-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/authorization-type": [ "app/common/authorization-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/message-pattern-type": [ "app/common/message-pattern-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/print-application-type": [ "app/common/print-application-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/temperature-object-type": [ "app/common/temperature-object-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/supply-chain-type": [ "app/common/supply-chain-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/package-status": [ "app/common/package-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/package-kind": [ "app/common/package-kind/index" ],
            "@ht/store/carrier-type": [ "app/common/carrier-type/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-direction": [ "app/common/route-direction/index" ],
            "@ht/store/printer": [ "app/common/printer/index" ],
            "@ht/store/message-modal": [ "app/common/message-modal/index" ],
            "@ht/store/task-modal": [ "app/common/task-modal/index" ],
            "@ht/store/loading-list": [ "app/common/loading-list/index" ],
            "@ht/store/loading-list-status": [ "app/common/loading-list-status/index" ],
            "@ht/store/truck-status-reason": [ "app/common/truck-status-reason/index" ],
            "@ht/store/package": [ "app/common/package/index" ],
            "@ht/store/contractor": [ "app/common/contractor/index" ],
            "@ht/store/contractor-warehouse": [ "app/common/contractor-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/store/driver": [ "app/common/driver/index" ],
            "@ht/store/truck-warehouse": [ "app/common/truck-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/store/transport": [ "app/common/transport/index" ],
            "@ht/store/transport-company": [ "app/common/transport-company/index" ],
            "@ht/store/route-confirm-loading": [ "app/common/route/confirm-loading/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/conctractor-contact": [ "app/modals/contractor-contact/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/conctractor-address": [ "app/modals/contractor-address/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/record-finder": [ "app/modals/record-finder/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/waybill/print": [ "app/modals/waybill/print/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/task": [ "app/modals/task/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/transport-company": [ "app/modals/transport-company/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/truck-zone": [ "app/modals/truck-zone/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/truck-type": [ "app/modals/truck-type/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/message": [ "app/modals/message/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/modal-reason-text": [ "app/modals/modal-reason-text/index"],
            "@ht/modal/package/block": [ "app/modals/package/block/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/package/cancel": [ "app/modals/package/cancel/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/package/confirm-status": [ "app/modals/package/confirm-status/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route/route-packages": [ "app/modals/route/route-packages/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route/mobile-params": [ "app/modals/route/mobile-params/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route/release-reservation": [ "app/modals/route/release-reservation/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route/add": [ "app/modals/route/add"],
            "@ht/modal/route/confirm-loading": [ "app/modals/route/confirm-loading"],
            "@ht/modal/loading-list/connect": [ "app/modals/loading-list/connect/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/loading-list/cancel": [ "app/modals/loading-list/cancel/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/route/cancel": [ "app/modals/route/cancel/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/bank-account-modal": [ "app/modals/bank-account/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/driver-authorization-modal": [ "app/modals/driver-authorization/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/temperature-recorder-modal": [ "app/modals/temperature-recorder/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/terminal": [ "app/modals/terminal/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/recorder-sensor-modal": [ "app/modals/temperature-recorder-sensor/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/mobile-terminal-modal": [ "app/modals/mobile-terminal/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/change-status-modal": ["app/modals/change-status"],
            "@ht/modal/visit-modal": [ "app/modals/visit/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/driver": [ "app/modals/driver/index" ],
            "@ht/modal/print-history-modal": [ "app/modals/print-history/index" ],
            "@ht/converters/tooltips": [ "app/converters/tooltips/index" ],
            "@ht/converters/transport-company": [ "app/converters/transport-company/index" ],
            "@ht/converters/map": [ "app/converters/common-map/index" ],
            "@ht/store/logger": [ "app/state/logger/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/converters": [ "app/endpoints/converters/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/seal-condition": [ "app/endpoints/seal-condition/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-reservation": [ "app/endpoints/truck-reservation/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-category1": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-category1/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-category-group": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-category-group/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/gallery":["app/endpoints/gallery/index"],
            "@ht/endpoint/terminal": [ "app/endpoints/terminal/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature-records": [ "app/endpoints/temperature-records/temperature/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature-object": [ "app/endpoints/temperature-records/temperature-object/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature-object-zone": [ "app/endpoints/temperature-records/temperature-object-zone/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature-sensor": [ "app/endpoints/temperature-sensor/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature-recorder": [ "app/endpoints/temperature-recorder/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-warehouse": [ "app/endpoints/truck-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/device-assignment-type": [ "app/endpoints/device-assignment-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-status":["app/endpoints/route-status/index"],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-point-status":["app/endpoints/route-point-status/index"],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-pauses":["app/endpoints/route-pauses/index"],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-direction": [ "app/endpoints/route-direction/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-temperature-recorder": [ "app/endpoints/route-temperature-recorder/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/device-ownership-type": [ "app/endpoints/device-ownership-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/device-state": [ "app/endpoints/device-state/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck": [ "app/endpoints/truck/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-class": [ "app/endpoints/truck-class/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-types": [ "app/endpoints/truck-types/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-zone": [ "app/endpoints/truck-zone/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/warehouse-zone": [ "app/endpoints/warehouse-zone/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/transport-company": [ "app/endpoints/transport-company/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/transport-company-iban": [ "app/endpoints/transport-company-iban/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/transport-company-truck": [ "app/endpoints/transport-company-truck/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/transport-company-type": [ "app/endpoints/transport-company-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-gif-history": [ "app/endpoints/truck-gif-history/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/driver": [ "app/endpoints/driver/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/driver-authorization": [ "app/endpoints/driver-authorization/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/print": [ "app/endpoints/print/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/currency": [ "app/endpoints/currency/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor": [ "app/endpoints/contractor/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-address": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-address/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-contact": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-contact/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-warehouse": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/contractor-type": [ "app/endpoints/contractor-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/distribution-centre": [ "app/endpoints/distribution-centre/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/warehouse": [ "app/endpoints/warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-template": [ "app/endpoints/route-template/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-template-customer": [ "app/endpoints/route-template-customer/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/package": [ "app/endpoints/package/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route": [ "app/endpoints/route/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-point": [ "app/endpoints/route-point/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-type":["app/endpoints/route-type/index"],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-task": [ "app/endpoints/route-task/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/route-confirmation": [ "app/endpoints/route-confirmation/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/attachment": [ "app/endpoints/attachment/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/seal": [ "app/endpoints/seal/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/search": [ "app/endpoints/search/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/settlement-subject-type": [ "app/endpoints/settlement-subject-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/truck-status-reason": [ "app/endpoints/truck-status-reason/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/message-pattern": [ "app/endpoints/message-pattern/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/mobile-process-params": [ "app/endpoints/mobile-process-params/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/notification": [ "app/endpoints/notification/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/user": [ "app/endpoints/user/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/invoice": [ "app/endpoints/invoice/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/invoice-payment-method": [ "app/endpoints/invoice-payment-method/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/invoice-status": [ "app/endpoints/invoice-status/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/package-kind": [ "app/endpoints/package-kind/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/package-invoice": [ "app/endpoints/package-invoice/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/supply-chain-type": [ "app/endpoints/supply-chain-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/document-kp-invoice": [ "app/endpoints/document-kp-invoice/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/document-kp": [ "app/endpoints/document-kp/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/document-kp-attachment": [ "app/endpoints/document-kp-attachment/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/document-kp-status": [ "app/endpoints/document-kp-status/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/carrier-type": [ "app/endpoints/carrier-type/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/package-status": [ "app/endpoints/package-status/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/temperature": [ "app/endpoints/temperature/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/loading-list": [ "app/endpoints/loading-list/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/loading-list-status": [ "app/endpoints/loading-list-status/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/waybill": [ "app/endpoints/waybill/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/waybill-status": [ "app/endpoints/waybill-status/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/printer": [ "app/endpoints/printer/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/user-warehouse": [ "app/endpoints/user-warehouse/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/role": [ "app/endpoints/role/index" ],
            "@ht/endpoint/print-history": [ "app/endpoints/print-history/index" ],
            "@ht/tools": ["app/shared/tools/index"],
            "@ht/models": ["app/shared/models/index"],
            "@ht/settlements/models": ["app/pages/settlements/models/index"],
            "@ht/settlements/services": ["app/pages/settlements/services/index"],
            "@ht/settlements/validators": ["app/pages/settlements/validators/index"],
            "@ht/planning/routes/components": ["app/pages/planning/routes/components/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/models": ["app/pages/planning/templates/models/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/services": ["app/pages/planning/templates/services/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/components": ["app/pages/planning/templates/components/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/containers": ["app/pages/planning/templates/containers/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/pipes": ["app/pages/planning/templates/pipes/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/validators": ["app/pages/planning/templates/validators/index"],
            "@ht/planning/templates/converters": ["app/pages/planning/templates/converters/index"],
            "@ht/report-viewer/models": ["app/pages/report-viewer/models/index"],
            "@ht/report-viewer/services": ["app/pages/report-viewer/services/index"],
            "@ht/report-viewer/components": ["app/pages/report-viewer/components/index"],
            "@ht/report-viewer/containers": ["app/pages/report-viewer/containers/index"],
            "@registries/components": ["app/pages/registries/components/index"],
            "@registries/containers": ["app/pages/registries/containers/index"],
            "@registries/services": ["app/pages/registries/services/index"],
            "@registries/models": ["app/pages/registries/models/index"],
            "@registries/validators": ["app/pages/registries/validators/index"],
            "@registries/contractor/models": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/contractors/models/index"],
            "@registries/contractor/services": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/contractors/services/index"],
            "@registries/driver/services": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/drivers/services/index"],
            "@registries/driver/containers": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/drivers/containers/index"],
            "@registries/driver/components": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/drivers/components/index"],
            "@registries/driver/models": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/drivers/models/index"],
            "@registries/driver/converters": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/drivers/converters/index"],
            "@registries/dictionaries/services": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/dictionaries/services/index"],
            "@registries/dictionaries/containers": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/dictionaries/containers/index"],
            "@registries/dictionaries/components": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/dictionaries/components/index"],
            "@registries/dictionaries/models": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/dictionaries/models/index"],
            "@registries/transport-companies/services": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport-companies/services/index"],
            "@registries/transport-companies/containers": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport-companies/containers/index"],
            "@registries/transport-companies/components": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport-companies/components/index"],
            "@registries/transport-companies/models": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport-companies/models/index"],
            "@registries/transport-companies/converters": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport-companies/converters/index"],
            "@registries/truck/services": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/services/index"],
            "@registries/truck/containers": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/containers/index"],
            "@registries/truck/components": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/components/index"],
            "@registries/truck/models": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/models/index"],
            "@registries/truck/converters": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/converters/index"],
            "@registries/truck/validators": ["app/pages/registries/subpages/transport/validators/index"],
            "@registries/distribution-centers/containers": [ "app/pages/registries/subpages/distribution-centers/containers/index" ],
            "@registries/distribution-centers/components": [ "app/pages/registries/subpages/distribution-centers/components/index" ],
            "@registries/distribution-centers/models": [ "app/pages/registries/subpages/distribution-centers/models/index" ],
            "@registries/distribution-centers/services": [ "app/pages/registries/subpages/distribution-centers/services/index" ],
            "@ht/packages/grid": ["app/common/grid/packages-registry-grid/index"],
            "@ht/temperatures/grid": ["app/common/grid/temperatures-grid/index"],
            "@ht/mobile-param": ["app/common/mobile-params/index"],
            "@ht/common-grid-toolbar": ["app/common/mat-toolbar-grid/index"]
        },
        "module": "esnext",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a path property in the mentioned tsconfig?

Comment: tsconfig.app.json added to question :)

Comment: The error is saying that you're missing the path property. I don't see one in that linked code. Have you tried adding one?

Comment: Actually, after looking around there doesn't seem to be a `path` property in the tsconfig schema. Can you try removing node_modules and your package lock and try reinstalling?

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: Probably I will try again on clear node modules ...